# How would I replace a word in a string that I know the start and ending to, but not the entire word? Ie: Converting an ID# to a name

Tags: php, regex

I am creating a web interface for a Discord bot I have created.  I currently store all user accounts, messages, etc in a SQL database so that the web interface can have extensive logs for the mods to use.  I am currently trying to come up with a solution for when viewing messages to convert "Discord Mentions" to readable names.

For example, when someone tags/mentions another user in a message, instead of the SQL storing '@name' it stores '<@!12345678>'. Based on how that text starts with <@! I know that it's linking a user name, in which I can access the SQL table containing all the users to retrieve their plain text name, but I'm not sure how to:

A) Specifically grab any words that both start with <@! and end with > to be able to grab the ID for a query and
B) Replace the the above <@!12345etc>, which is easy enough to do once I know how to do A.

**Just for clarification I'm not looking for help doing SQL query, just looking for help in getting the entire word that stats with <@! and ends with > from a string/paragraph.**

I'm terrible with regex so hopefully there is a solution that can work without needing it haha.  Any tips you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

TLDR:

Sample string:

"Hey <@!123456789> thanks for that, I'll get back to you sooon."

How to get the grab the entire word that starts with <@! and ends with > to be able to do SQL query with it and then a replace() later.

I thought about exploding the string with a space and then going through each word one at a time checking each word with startswith and endswith but if the message author didn't leave a space between mentions and the rest of the text that wouldn't work.

Comment: AKA "token" replacement. (try adding that to some search phrases - feel like a lot of examples of str_replace vs preg, even some libs you could evaluate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<?php

$str = "Hey <@!123456789> thanks for that, I'll get back to you sooon.";    
$re = '/(?<=<@!).+?(?=>)/m';


preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// flatten the array result (otherwise it's an array of arrays)
$matches = array_merge(...$matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches); //Array ( [0] => 123456789 )
```

Demo https://3v4l.org/D64Ma

Regex explanation:

> `(?<=<@!)` looksbehind to find `<@!`. This starts the match
>
> `.+?` matches any character any number of times until next lookahead.
>
> `(?=>)` match ends when `>` is found (but not included in match)

The difference between using lookaheads and lookbehinds and regular `/<@!(.+?)>` is the `matches` array that they produce.

Lookarounds are not included in the matching group and results in an array of arrays containing all the matching groups ("12345678") only.

Not wrapping the start `<@!` and end `>` in a lookaround results in an array of arrays containing both the regex pattern match ("<@!12345678>", plus matching group ("12345678"). So you would have to extract the matching groups from the resulting arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly you want all the values between "<@!" and ">". That being said I believe all you need is this `/<@!(.+)>/g`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/SXF04Y/1)

Comment: You can also do `<@!([^>]+)>` for a faster regex. And add the unicode flag if that makes sense (i don't remember discord's rules for user names).

Comment: I almost asked how you are determining the speed of the regex until I realized regex101 gives you a count.

Comment: That is an awesome feature! :)